# android - Animation prevents click event

Tags: android

I'm new on game dev for Android.

I have a game where I need to click on moving Buttons or TextViews(not important). 
I extended FrameLayout class and added some Buttons(through addView method). Then I tried to use TranslateAnimation, but it seems it doesn't updates coordinates for click event (i.e. when I click on the moving button on new position, the event is not handling, but when I click on the origin place(where it has started moving), the event catches even if the button left this place).

**Question**: How to create a moveable label(or button) that handles click events? Do I need to use tricks like hit testing? Or, may be I use completely wrong approach for games(e.g. I need to draw text instead of adding the views in layout)? I will be happy if you can suggest another solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is limitation of the Animation in Android. They fixed that in Android 3.0. Read here for more information http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html

An excerpt:

"Finally, the previous animations changed the visual appearance of the target objects... but they didn't actually change the objects themselves. You may have run into this problem. Let's say **you want to move a Button from one side of the screen to the other**. You can use a **TranslateAnimation** to do so, and the button will happily glide along to the other side of the screen. And when the animation is done, it will gladly snap back into its original location. So you find the setFillAfter(true) method on Animation and try it again. This time the button stays in place at the location to which it was animated. And you can verify that by clicking on it - Hey! **How come the button isn't clicking? The problem is that the animation changes where the button is drawn, but not where the button physically exists within the container.** If you want to click on the button, you'll have to click the location that it used to live in. Or, as a more effective solution (and one just a tad more useful to your users), you'll have to write your code to actually change the location of the button in the layout when the animation finishes."

Comment: So, it seems need to write own animation class? Indeed, there is no much better solution?

Comment: I actually don't know how to resolve this in android < 3.0, I just know what's the cause of the problem.